# Find all newlines in richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I am working on a custom texteditor control and encountered this problem.

I need a function that gets the character indexes for every newline "\n" in the text.
I already have two ways to accomplish this:

```
private List<int> GetNewLineLocations()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        int ix = 0;
        foreach (var c in this.Text)
        {
            if (c == '\n') list.Add(ix);
            ix++;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(ix);
        return list;
    }
```

And:

```
private List<int> GetNewLineLocations()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        int ix = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            ix += Lines[i].Length;
            ix += 1;
            list.Add(ix);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

The first solution does work but slows down the more text is entered in the richtextbox that is around 40000 characters but that can be spread out among a lot of rows like 20000.

The second one seems to be faster because it loops less and does more or less the same but is slows down dramatically at 1000 rows no mater how much text they contain.

The code of course needs to run fast and not use a lot of resources that is why I thought the second solution would be better.

**My question is:**

1. Which solution is better and why?
2. Why is the second solution so much slower?
3. Is there an even better solution?

Comment: [TextBoxBase.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline)

Comment: Unfortunately i could not get that to work.

Comment: At least not better and faster

Comment: You don't need to parse the `\n` chars & store indexes. You already have the collection of Lines [TextBoxBase.Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines) and 
`TextBoxBase.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine` will return the index of each starting char in a specific line. Use only when really needed using the provided indexers: `int CharIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(100);`

Comment: Make sure you check out the [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2) to measure processing time and compare you algorithms

Comment: I've actually made an editor like that, and I always used a helper function to get the current line number and the position on that line, by using `rtb.SelectionStart`, `rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(...)` and `rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(...)`. Once you got that you can just process the single line from `rtb.Lines[...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both of your examples and Felix's and a solution of my own using a rich text box and 40k lines. The result was this was the fastest, and I saw no slow down. Can you try passing the array of lines as a paramater and let us know the result?

```
public static List<int> GetNewLineLocations(this string[] lines)
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            int ix = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                ix += lines[i].Length+1;
                list.Add(ix);
            }

            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Summing the line length in parallel is not possible because the processing order is chaotic. You result would be wrong.

Comment: You should overthink your application designe and store you date not in your userinterface. [Check your Front/Backend seperation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends). Storing your data in a backend will allow you to access your data directly without depending in your Textbox methods.

Comment: @Felix - where do you see anything in parallel?

Comment: Thank you for your help the parameter was the solution.

Comment: Your welcome, I let someone smarter than me why using the object reference in the iterator is so much slower.

Answer (score 0):

When working with strings [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2) are very nice to use. But they are not the fastest. If you need faster processing you should do it on lower levels and in parallel. And make sure to use long as index because int only allow you to process up to 2^31 chars, and long up to 2^63 chars.

I agree with [@Nyerguds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395685/nyerguds)
who sayed in the comments:

> The problem is that the standard function to fetch the text in a rich text box is actually a processing function that has to filter out the RTF markup. The actual function to fetch the text is the bottleneck, not what comes after it.

So your data should be held somewhere in the code and not in the userinterface. Sooner or later when processing long texts that will cause trouble anyway, like stuttering when scrolling or further bottlenecks. And I would only represent the lines that could be displayed in the control anyway. So you should overthink your application design. [Check your Front/Backend seperation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends) Storing your data in a backend will allow you to access your data directly without depending in your Textbox methods or other userinterface stuff.

Here is a sample how to easy process data with the [Parallel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) of the .net framework:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            public static byte[] _globalDataStore { get; set; }
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                DoStuff();
                ShowDone();
            }

            private static void ShowDone()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("done...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            private static void DoStuff()
            {
                var tempData = GetData();
                StoreData(ref tempData);
                tempData = null; //free some ram
                var dataIdentifier = (byte)'\n';
                GetAndPromptDataPositions(_globalDataStore, dataIdentifier);
            }

            private static void GetAndPromptDataPositions<T>(T[] data, T dataIdentifier)
            {
                var dataPositionList = GetDataPositions<T>(data, dataIdentifier);
                PromptDataPostions(dataPositionList);
            }

            private static void PromptDataPostions(IEnumerable<long> positionList)
            {
                foreach (var position in positionList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Position '{position}'");
                }
            }
            private static string GetData()
            {
                return "aasdlj\naksdlkajsdlkasldj\nasld\njkalskdjasldjlasd";
            }

            private static void StoreData(ref string tempData)
            {
                _globalDataStore = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tempData);
            }

            private static List<long> GetDataPositions<T>(T[] data, T dataToFind)
            {
                lock (data) //prevent data from being changed while processing, important when have other threaded could write data 
                {
                    var postitonList = new List<long>();
                    Parallel.For(0, data.LongLength, (position) =>
                    {
                        if (data[position].Equals(dataToFind))
                        {
                            lock (postitonList) //lock list because of multithreaded access to prevent data corruption
                            {
                                postitonList.Add(position);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return postitonList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that the standard function to fetch the text in a rich text box is actually a processing function that has to filter out the RTF markup. The _actual function to fetch the text_ is the bottleneck, not what comes after it.

Comment: You are right. Thought about something like that also. In my oppinion the data should be held in a byte array somewhere in the code and not in the controls properties. Sooner or later when processing long texts that will cause trouble anyway, like stuttering when scrolling. I would only present the lines that could be displayed in the control anyway.